# Is it possible to call a Javascript function before every request to the server?

Tags: javascript, http

I am having some content in local storage . I want to send this in http header every time a request to the server is being made by invoking something like (xhr.setRequestHeader('custom-header', 'value');). Instead of calling the function which does this task before every request , I want it to be called automatically .

Comment: So can't you make a method that builds the XHR object that does this? Call the method instead of invoking the XHR directly.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup: I'm not seeing a `dojo` tag or any other indication the OP is using Dojo.

Comment: @epascarello  I am having some content in local storage . I want to send this in http header every time a request to the server is being made . instead of calling the function which does this task before every request , I want it to be called automatically . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done easily by overwriting the `send` method:

```
// save the real `send`
var realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

// replace `send` with a wrapper
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    this.setRequestHeader("X-Foobar", "my header content");

    // run the real `send`
    realSend.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This turns `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` into a function that does some arbitrary operation (here, setting the `X-Foobar` request header on the `XMLHttpRequest` instance) and then executes the actual Ajax request with the real `send` method.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage was actually designed *not* to be sent to the server automatically. This was done to improve on cookies, which result in a large overhead (if they hold much data) due to their being sent with every page request. That slows things down and makes is very bad for mobile phones particularly. So you will have to continue with the method you are already using, or take one of the alternative suggestions offered in other replies.